# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.jpcap")

Tags: java, javafx-2, jpcap, accesscontrolexception

I have an application for my school project which has jpcap classes and I get these exceptions when trying to run the jar file:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.jpcap")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkLink(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.<clinit>(JpcapCaptor.java:251)
... 12 more
```

Is there any way to permit my code without adding:

```
grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };
```

to jre location\lib\security\java.policy?

Answer (score 0):

For all of you who have this same problem:

1. First, you will have to add a `MANIFEST.MF` file to your applet. Check: [Simpliest way to add an attribute to a jar Manifest in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645337/simpliest-way-to-add-an-attribute-to-a-jar-manifest-in-maven) for a way for signing and adding the manifest file to your applet. *Make sure that this configuration isn't override in the applet parameters configurations*.
2. Java 8+ requires signed applets, so you will have to sign your applet. If you are in a development environment you will have to self-sign your applet and add this certificate to the Java Control Panel. See this for [a way to add Self-Signed Certificates to the List of Trusted Certificates in the Java Runtime](http://pitss.com/us/2014/05/15/how-to-add-self-signed-certificates-to-the-list-of-trusted-certificates-in-the-java-runtime/) .
3. Even after that, there is some code that will run only with `PrivilegedActions`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1730904/2692914.

Anyway, this is how I have done this, I've used this [Minimal Java Applet built with Maven as a base project](https://github.com/ansoncat/minimal-java-applet-maven).

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Name: One Applet
Codebase: *
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Trusted-Only: false
Trusted-Library: false
```

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <index>true</index>
            <manifestFile>${project.basedir}/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attached</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <keystore>src/main/resources/minimal-keystore.jks</keystore>
        <alias>minimal</alias>
        <storepass>abcd1234</storepass>
        <keypass>abcd1234</keypass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sign</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
</plugins>
</build>
```

**minimal.cer**

```
keytool -export -keystore minimal-keystore.jks -alias minimal -file minimal.cer
```

[image: Adding cert to the Java Control Panel]

**SomeClass.java**

```
try {
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
        public Object run() {
            try {
                for (String dll : dlls) {
                    String dllPath = basePath + dll;
                    System.out.println("Cargando: " + dllPath);
                    System.load(dllPath);
                }
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```

Well, that's it!